# sapui5 complex data binding

Tags: javascript, data-binding, sapui5

I have the following JSON-Model:

```
{
    "Auctions": [{
        "AuctionsTypes": [{
            "AuctionType": "Contract",
            "Auctions": [{
                "AuctionID": "12345"
            }, {
                "AuctionID": "54321"
            }]
        },{
            "AuctionType": "Delivery",
            "Auctions": [{
                "AuctionID": "12345"
            }, {
                "AuctionID": "54321"
            }]
        }]
    }]
}
```

My JS:

```
var oAuctionsModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
oAuctionsModel.loadData("model/mock_auction_types.json");
oView.setModel(oAuctionsModel, "auctions");
```

I would like to output the `AuctionsType` in a list but this code doesn't work. The list is empty.

```
<List id="idListAuctions" items="{auctions>/Auctions/AuctionsTypes}">
  <items>
    <StandardListItem title="{auctions>AuctionType}" type="Navigation" press="doSomething" />
  </items>
</List>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your data, `Auctions` is an array itself, so you have to specify which array element inside you would like to access.

In your example, the first one:

```xml
<List items="{auctions>/Auctions/0/AuctionsTypes}">
    <StandardListItem title="{auctions>AuctionType}" />
</List>
```